# Start the process as child process to service

Tags: c++, winapi

I have handle to a service and handle to a process. Is it possible to restart this process as a child process to service? If yes how can I do it?

Both this service and process are created by some other application, here I am getting handle to those.

Getting handle for service:

```
schService = OpenService(schSCManager, ServiceName, SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG);
```

Getting handle to the process:

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);
```

I want to stop and start `hprocess` as child for `schservice`.

Comment: show us what you've tried

Comment: Windows doesn't really have the concept of parent/child process that you find in *nix. The parent is just the process that called `CreateProcess` and the parent can quite happily terminate leaving the child to continue on without its parent. If you have handles to two processes, then the processes already exist. What is your actual problem? Why do you ask?

Comment: `OpenService()` does not return a handle to a running service process.

Comment: @ojas: what you are asking for is a security breach waiting to happen. What are you REALLY trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to restart this process as a child process to service?

Not easily, if at all.  You would have to query the process for the command-line that originally spawned it, and then inject code into the running service process to launch a new copy of that same command-line using `CreateProcess()` or `CreateProcessAsUser()`.  Of course, if the service is running in a higher integrity/security level than your injector is running in, you won't be able to inject code into it.

> I want to stop and start `hprocess` as child for `schservice`.

Why?  There is no real benefit for doing that.  Unless you are trying to circumvent the OS's security to make the process run in a higher integrity/security level than it was already running in.  And that would be a very dangerous security breach if the OS allowed that.